# update an item with animation in RecyclerView Adapter

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I am using RcyclerView adapter which holding a chat messages list.

every time a message added to firebase I am using the 'onChildAdded' listener to update the adapter list. I also want to update certain messages by adding their background a changing color-animation.
the problem is I don't know how to access the position of specific messages in my adapter.

this is my chatListadapter:

```
class ChatListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
    private List<ChatMessage> msgList;
    private static final int VIEW_TYPE_MESSAGE_LEFT = 1;
    private static final int VIEW_TYPE_MESSAGE_RIGHT = 2;
    private DataReferences DB;

    ChatListAdapter(List<ChatMessage> msgList) {
        this.msgList = msgList;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return msgList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        DB = DataReferences.getInstance();
        ChatMessage msg = msgList.get(position);
        if (!msg.uid.equals(DB.uid)) {
                return VIEW_TYPE_MESSAGE_LEFT;
            }
        } else
            return VIEW_TYPE_MESSAGE_RIGHT;
    }



    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view;

        if (viewType == VIEW_TYPE_MESSAGE_LEFT) {
            view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.message_received, parent, false);
            return new LeftViewHolder(view);
        } else {
            view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.message_sent, parent, false);
            return new RightViewHolder(view);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int 
     position) {
        ChatMessage msg = msgList.get(position);
        if (msg.critic)
            switch (holder.getItemViewType()) {
                case VIEW_TYPE_MESSAGE_LEFT:
                    ((LeftViewHolder) holder).bind(msg);
                    break;
                case VIEW_TYPE_MESSAGE_RIGHT:
                    ((RightViewHolder) holder).bind(msg);
                    break;
            }
 
    @Override
    public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    }

    private class LeftViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView messageText, timeText, nameText;
        public LeftViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            timeText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_message_time);
            nameText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_message_name);
            messageText = (TextView) 
           itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_message_body);
        }

        void bind(ChatMessage message) {
            messageText.setText(message.getMsg());
            timeText.setText(message.getTime());
            nameText.setText(message.UserName);
        }
    }

    private class RightViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView messageText, timeText;

        public RightViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            timeText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_message_time);
            messageText = (TextView) 
              itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_message_body);
        }
        void bind(ChatMessage message) {
            messageText.setText(message.getMsg());
            timeText.setText(message.getTime());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Also code to go off would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to used `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` which come in `FirebaseUI` library (https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/README.md). It makes handling data in `RecyclerView` become easier.

To make adapter update specific item. In `populateViewHolder` of `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` you could do something like this (suppose you want to change message background if the message has been read)

```
 override fun populateViewHolder(viewHolder: FieldViewHolder?, model: Message, position: Int) {
                if(model.isRead) {
                    viewholder.updateBackground()
                }
        }
```

If you use plain `RecyclerView` it might need some effort to find specific position and update UI accordingly.

Hope it's help.

Comment: I think I can save the position value on firebase and every time I want to change specific message, I will access this value and then I will call 'notifyItemChanged'. but my question is how can I save this value the first time I add each message to the adapter??